# Generic Model Classes

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am working with some web services and there are many web services which I use in order to retrieve information. Since there are many web services, I have created a model class in order to map the result from web services.

All though the web services' response structure is same, content is different. So I have created a generic model to grab the response like below.

```
public class GenericResponse<T> {
    private List<T> Results;
    private ErrorResponseModel Status;

    public List<T> getResults() {
        return Results;
    }

    public ErrorResponseModel getStatus() {
        return Status;
    }
}
```

I want this result to assign to relevant models, so I can access data with getters.

```
List<SomeModelClass> result= webServiceResponse.getResults();
```

But using above way, when I try to access getters, it gives the below mentioned error.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap cannot be cast to...
```

What is the proper way of doing this?

> **NOTE:** There is a way of doing this, which I have tried, you can convert this reponse to a Gson, and then deserializing it using the
>   relevant object class. That way it works, but don't know whether it's
>   the good practice.

Answer (score 1):

Problem with your class is, you are always expecting result to be a list.
What you could do, will be change results to be   `private T result`, in this case if your result will be String, then T will be a String, if result will be List of Foos, thet T will be `List<Foo>`.

**EDIT**

If you have a problem with serialisation of your result, you need to define `JsonDeserializer` for that type(s).

```
     class MyResultDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<MyResult>() {
       public Id deserialize(JsonElement json, Type type, JsonDeserializationContext context)
           throws JsonParseException {
         return new MyResult(id.getValue());
       }
}
```

and register it

```
GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder()
builder.registerTypeAdapter(MyResult.class, new MyResultDeserializer());
```

Comment: Yes, I am always expecting a List. It's a fixed thing. Only the list content would be different.